What is the "#pragma" directive in C++?
I was reading and came across the #pragma directive, so I decided to do some research. However, I didn't understand much and would like to see if someone can shortly explain it to me about the #pragma directive, because I don't understand the websites about it like cppreference, suggested by wohlstad, and I am just a beginner in C++. Thanks for any help!
(Edit: I saw a comment by Botje about what comes after #pragma, but I just want to know all of its uses so that I can use it in the future.)

depends on what word comes after #pragma...

Most probably you are see #pragma once. Here is documentation for gcc for any #pragma.

It's always compiler specific. There are few "common" pragmas, but even those you have to verify with your compiler first. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/impl

Some info from cppreference: Implementation defined behavior control.

Usually it means a compiler specific command comes after, it is at least not something from standard C++. In general don't use it in portable code.  So if you want to know more you will have to lookup the documentation of your compiler to know which "extensions" it provides

Side note, you will do yourself a big favor by learning to read cppreference (and the C++ core guidelines too). But maybe just start with a site like learncpp.com to get yourself familiar with the basics of C++

I use Code::Blocks. Can it fulfill the requirements? https://www.codeblocks.org/

Codeblocks is a proram to edit source code, it is not the compiler itself. So you will still need to find out what compiler your install is using.

In general, don't use it. It has no portable semantics; it's entirely up to the compiler writer to decide what it means.

@PeteBecker I don't know of any compiler that doesn't support #pragma once, but I've already invested multiple hours in different projects with other developers to debug bugs in include guards. I would always prefer #pragma once.

@jabaa -- "I don't know of any ..." isn't the same as "there are no ...". But what, exactly, is the specification for #pragma once? Is an exact duplicate of a file, in a different location, "the same"? Is a file on a network, reached through a path that traverses different servers, easily recognizable a "the same"? There's no way to know, within the code you write, whether two #include directives will satisfy #pragma once; with include guards (correctly written, of course) you know exactly what you're getting.

@PeteBecker Yes, I know that some very special compilers and use-cases exist. I've never included the same header files through different paths and I assume, that 90%-99% of all C++ developers never have done this and will never do it. I would say, that for at least 90% #pragma once is the better option. And the other 10% are so specialized and experienced that they know what to do. I know, that the situation was different in the past, but today, I don't even know a C++ developer that regularly uses a compiler other than GCC, Clang or MSVC.

@jabaa -- you're missing my point. Yes, you can identify particular things that you suspect #pragma once won't get right and you can try to avoid them. Is that all of them, or are there other failures lurking in your build system? Include guards put the logic in the source code; #pragma once puts it somewhere else. How do you know what it does?

@PeteBecker I've read documentation and talked with dozens of developers, and to this day I don't know one thing that could cause problems in the projects I've worked in. If there is something I don't know and that could cause problems in common projects with common use-cases and common tool chain, I was lucky. Instead, in almost all projects someone had to fix an include guard, either in a code review or later. Both methods have advantages and disadvantages, but until today I made much better experience with #pragma once than with include guards.

@PeteBecker Maybe your opinion is right. I only wanted to say, that at least one user has a different opinion about this. "Don't use it" is an opinion and not a consensus in the C++ community.

#pragma directive is a way to tell compiler to act in some special way, usually to do something that cannot be specified by using standard C++. The C++ standard doesn't define any #pragmas. Those are all specific to some particular compiler(s). But the C++ standard says (in [cpp.pragma]): Any pragma that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored. Thus, there might be arbitrarily many different #pragmas used by different compilers, and to know them all, you'll have to read documentation for every C++ compiler on earth.

@jabaa -- you misquoted me. I didn't say "don't use it". I said "In general, don't use it". There's a world of difference. Not to mention that you've run off on #pragma once when my comment was about #pragma itself. Beginners don't need to know about pragmas.
